# How to waterfall angular actions or effect where the result of the previous action or effect determines the next step

Tags: angular, rxjs, action, store, effects

I have the following effects

```
  /**
   * Step 1: This action triggers a data flush
   */
  @Effect()
  loadStripeForUse$ = this._actions$.pipe(
    ofType<LoadStripeForUse>(EStripeActions.LoadStripeForUse),
    map( () => new PreLoadStripeAPIDataClear())
  );

  /**
   * Step 2: This action handles a data flush and triggers API request for
   * stripe keys
   */
  @Effect()
  preLoadStripeAPIDataClear$ = this._actions$.pipe(
    ofType<PreLoadStripeAPIDataClear>(EStripeActions.PreLoadStripeAPIDataClear),
    concatMap(() => [
      new PreLoadStripeAPIDataClearSuccess(),
      new PostCreateStripePaymentIntentKeys()
    ])
  );

  /**
   * Step 3: Grab Stripe keys then save keys and pass keys onto call for Stripe API
   */
  @Effect()
  postCreateStripePaymentIntentKeys$ = this._actions$.pipe(
    ofType<PostCreateStripePaymentIntentKeys>(EStripeActions.PostCreateStripePaymentIntentKeys),
    switchMap((action) => this._restApiService.stripeCreateStripePaymentIntentKeysPost()),
    concatMap( (payload: IStripePaymentIntentKeys) => [
      new PostCreateStripePaymentIntentKeysSuccess(payload),
      new LoadStripeApi(payload)
    ])
  );

  /**
   * Step 4: Load Stripe API with keys then store Stripe API in store for use
   */
  @Effect()
  loadStripeApi$ = this._actions$.pipe(
    ofType<LoadStripeApi>(EStripeActions.LoadStripeApi),
    switchMap((action) => this._restApiService.loadStripe(action.payload.public_key)),
    concatMap ( (stripe: Stripe) => [
      new LoadStripeApiSuccess(stripe),
      new LoadStripeForUseSuccess(stripe)
    ])
  );
```

Ideally I would like to be able to have each effect handling its own functionality and bundle them all into a single effect where they waterfall. Like so

```
  @Effect()
  idealloadStripeApi$ = this._actions$.pipe(
    ofType<LoadStripeApi>(EStripeActions.IdealLoadStripeApi),
    // 1. Flush data action
    // 2. Confirm data is flushed
    // 3. Load Stripe keys
    // 4. Confirm keys are loaded and saved
    // 5. Load Stripe API
    // 6. Confirm Stripe API is loaded
    // 7. Success
  );
```

I have seen numerous posts citing the use of switchMap, concatMap where the target is an observable, but I want to track the success/failure of an action/effect within an effect and then progress to the next action/effect and so on.
How can this be achieved?

Comment: it is possible, but it will be a nested pieces of code with growing level on each branching or multiple actions. it will look worse than your original code

Comment: Thats a huge shame but does seem consistent with my research :( A waterfall feature would be so helpful